# How to create hyper-link in terminal window python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I am new to python. I want to create hyper-link in **terminal window** using python. How can I achieve this? (The link as-it-is is clickable in terminal)

Suppose I have a link https://duckduckgo.com and want to hyper-link to text *duckduckgo* (Text should be clickable ofcourse).

[HTML version would be]

```
<a href="https://duckduckgo.com">duckduckgo</a>
```

Comment: This would totally depend on whether or not the terminal emulator even supports this, which I've never actually encountered, which to be fair, I've never actually needed, so maybe it is supported...

Comment: I'm not sure if this verifies terminal's support - But the w3m browser always displays links in hyper-link format.

Comment: You are not going to find this capability with any out-of-the-box terminal as far as I know. Try looking into the [Hyper](https://hyper.is/) terminal and the [hyperlinks](https://github.com/zeit/hyperlinks) extension.

Comment: But I don't think terminal should be an issue here. I am using xfce4-terminal, and it supports clickable links. I want to hyper-link a url link to some text (to shorten the link basically).

Comment: @mi0xz right, but there is no guarantee that is supported, and certainly, Python doesn't have any way of knowing. That is completely up to whether or not xfce4-terminal supports it. You'd be better off tagging this question with the right terminal and asking specifically about that.

Comment: Okay thank you. My aim is just to shorten URL links - like torrent magnetic links so that they fit nicely in terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**:  I want to create hyper-link in terminal window using python.

Instead of writing to `Terminal Window`, create a temporary `HTML File` using Python and open this `HTML File` with your default Browser or even with click at **one** short URL in the `Terminal Window`.

Also possible to launch your default Browser from within a Python script using `module subprocess`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and report back.

Comment: Update: Though it did not produce the intended output, this gave me a new insight for my ongoing project. Thanks.